# Error:(72) error: junk after document element

Tags: android

I'm reading this code and I'm still don't know how to fix it.

*I can't check the app, cuz it doesn't work cuz of those mistakes.
I have tried to reread the whole code my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and it reformated the code, but the errors are still here.*

I added a comments where i see the errors - **I have 3 errors.** Into message I'm getting comment: *Error:(72) error: junk after document element.*

That would be nice, if you can help me. Thx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/music"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/this_is_main_menu"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/menuPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_headset_black_24dp" />
            <TextView
                style="@style/menuItemText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/player"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>


<!-- below error multiple root tags-->
    <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/menuPlaylists"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/menuItemText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/playlist"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

 <!--below error: multiple root tags-->   
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="NestedWeights">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/menuAlbums"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_library_music_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/menuItemText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/albums"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <!--below: error: multiple root tags-->  
<LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/menuItemText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/frame"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
 <!--below: error: unexpected tokens-->   
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** There can be multiple causes of this, so I try addressing them all to handle different cases, since there are multiple reasons why there's a problem.

---

## Case 1: Multiple roots in a singel file by intent

For one, you define multiple document root tags in the same fine. Split them into multiple files, or use a single root. This means this isn't allowed:

somefile.xml:

```
<tag>...</tag>
<tag>...</tag>
<tag>...</tag>
```

It has to be:

```
<tag>
    <tag>...</tag>
    <tag>...</tag>
</tag>
```

## Case 2: Single layout

However: Your source seems to have an unwanted tag closing. After you close the CardView:

```
<RelativeLayout (first tag>
....

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
<Another layout>
```

Remove the `</RelativeLayout>` tag; it exists at the end of the file, which is why it's marked as an unexpected token. It doesn't close anything because the layout it should close already is closed. Remove the early closing of the RelativeLayout and it'll fix the other issues too, as they come as a result of the early tag closing

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the  below line which is on line number 70:

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

which is above your first error `<!-- below error multiple root tags-->` and then try it.